# Return value in a method that call stored procedure

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I am using the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary` for accessing a SQL Server database in my C# code. I have a method that call the stored procedure and send a parameter to the stored procedure, and that stored procedure returns a row (username and password).

I am not sure how return the value in this method.

This is my code:

```
public Model.Login GetUsernameandPasswordByPartnerID(int partnerId)
{
        Model.Login login;

        string myConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ToString();
        SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(myConnection);

        using (DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("AS_AuthenticateByPartner"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "partnerID", DbType.String, partnerId);

            try
            {
                login = db.ExecuteScalar(command); //error on this line

                // rtn = Message("Success", "Acquisition", "GetLogin", "Service", db.ExecuteScalar(command).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            db = null;
            return login;
        }
    }
```

and my Model.login

```
public class Login
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
}
```

I am not sure how should have this line:

```
 login=  db.ExecuteScalar(command);
```

now I am getting error as you cannot explicitly convert object to `Model.login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of object is return of following statement.

```
login=  db.ExecuteScalar(command);
```

You have to do something like this

```
login=  (Model.Login)db.ExecuteScalar(command);
```

But this is not solve your problem as ExecuteScalar does not return .net type Login. It is only useful if you return int ,string etc from SQL Server. To help on this I need  to know what is return from your stored procedure.

If I assume that you are returning something like this

```
 select username,password from tblUser
```

Then you can not use ExecuteScalar as it is only use to return single value.

You have to do something like this.

```
 Model.Login model = null;
 var result  =  db.ExecuteReader();
 if (!reader.HasRows)
    model = null;
 else 
  {
        reader.Read();
        model = new Model.Login(){ UserName = reader.GetString(0) , Password=  reader.GetString(1) };
  }
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve data as objects using Enterprise Library, then you should consider using the data accessors.  See [Retrieving Data as Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664742(v=pandp.50).aspx) for a description (it's for version 5 but applies equally for version 6).

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteScalar` method is typically used to return a single value from the database.

Try this instead. I'm assuming the stored procedure will return *at most* a single record with a matching username and password.

```
using (var command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("AS_AuthenticateByPartner"))
{
    db.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    db.AddInParameter(command, "partnerID", DbType.String, partnerId);

    // make sure myConnection is open before querying the database

    var reader = db.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader.HasRows)
        return null;  // no records found... return null? display error?

    reader.Read();

    return new Login {username = reader.GetString(0), password = reader.GetString(1)};
}
```

This code specifies that the command text is a stored procedure. And it uses `ExecuteReader()` to get back (potentially) multiple records from the database, as a result of the query.

Also, FWIW, don't use empty `catch` blocks. Silently eating exceptions is never good... something may be going wrong and you'd never know about it.